# Spivak, Chapter 8 "Least Upper Bounds", Problem 5c: for $r<s$ rational numbers, prove there is irrational number between $r$ and $s$?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

> 5c) Suppose that $r<s$ are rational numbers. Prove that there is an
> irrational number between $r$ and $s$. Hint: as a start, you know
> there is an irrational number between $0$ and $1$.

There is no solution for this problem in the solution manual to Spivak's Calculus.

What irrational number is obviously between $0$ and $1$? This is chapter 8 of Spivak's Calculus, and the only proofs in the book so far touching on this matter are

1. a proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, given before the least upper bound property was introduced:

> If $A$ is a set of real numbers, $A \neq \emptyset$, and A bounded
> above, then $A$ has a least upper bound.

and

2. a proof that every positive number has a square root (ie, 2 has a square root), and the proof depends on the least upper bound property.

Therefore, I'm guessing he means $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is an irrational between $0$ and $1$.

**My Proof of 5c**

Since $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous, and since $f(1)=1<2<4=f(2)$, $\exists x \in (1,2)$ such that $f(x)=x^2=2$. We denote such an $x$ as $\sqrt{2}$, and therefore $\sqrt{2} \in (1,2)$. We can also prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

Therefore, $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<1$.

We need the following lemmas:

**Lemma 1:** the sum or difference of a rational and an irrational number is irrational.

**Lemma 2:** if $a$ is irrational, then $\frac{1}{a}$ is irrational.

**Lemma 3:** if $a$ and $b$ are rational, so are $a+b$ and $a-b$.

Therefore, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational.

Now, given rational $r$ and $s$, with $r$ < $s$, let $d=r-s>0$.

There are only two possible cases: $d > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $d < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Note that $d = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is not possible, because if this is true then $r-s$ is irrational, contradicting lemma 3.

**Case 1:** $d > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Let $n=s+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Then $n$ is irrational and

$$s<n<s+d=r$$

**Case 2:** $d<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Let $i_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Then $0<d<i_1<1$.

If we find an irrational number $m$ between $0$ and $d$, we are in case 1 again with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ replaced by $m$.

The number $i_2=i_1-d$ is irrational and $0<i_2<i_1$.

In part b) of this problem we proved

> $x<y \implies \exists r \in \mathbb{Q}$, $x<r<y$

Thus, $\exists r_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $0<i_2<r_1<i_1$.

Subtract $i_2$

Then, $0<r_1-i_2<i_1-i_2=d$

But $r_1-i_2$ is irrational, since it is the difference between a rational and an irrational number.

Thus we have found $m=r_1-i_2=r_1+d-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ that is irrational and $0<m<d$. Thus we are in case 1, and so if we let $n=s+m$, then $n$ is irrational and $s<n<s+d=r$.

Comment: Your lemma should say $s < r$. Also, there is something a little bit perverse about using continuity to prove the existence of a real number, since the intermediate value theorem is a consequence of the properties of the real numbers. Though, of course, such things are standard practice.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the proof of the existence of the square root of any positive number? Spivak gives us 12 properties of "numbers" to start the book. He doesn't include the 13th property: least upper bound property. With the twelve, one can define limits and continuity, but one cannot prove the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVM); Spivak claims it is impossible on page 128. The proof of IVM requires the least upper bound property. With the introduction of the latter the proof of existence of square roots is possible.

Comment: Spivak also claims in his text that this proof is impossible on the basis of the first twelve properties alone.

Comment: Because you apparently haven't figured this out yet: Any problem with reasonably complete answers at the back of the textbook itself does not have solutions in the solutions manual.

Comment: @TedShifrin true now that you mention it. :) My proof is a much more complicated version of that (much simpler) proof which is to just choose the irrational number $r+\sqrt{2}\frac{s-r}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, the point is that $a+t(b-a)$ will be in the segment $[a,b]$ when $t\in [0,1]$. And $0<1/\sqrt2<1$. :)